# Read HttpResponse of URL after using HttpPost to submit form log-in

Tags: java, android, forms, apache, http

I hope that the title of my question accurately describes the problem I'm having, but in case it doesn't...

I'm using HttpPost to submit a form to log-in to a website (my schools'), and am testing to see what happens if I put in bogus information into the username/ password fields; for example, if for my username I input "Kioop", and for my password, "jukli", I want to read that HttpResponse. I've looked at the source code for what happens when I login successfully and when I don't login successfully, and when I don't successfully login it displays a little error message: "Couldn't login..." However, when I try to read that using an InputStream, I only get the original source code of the URL. Sorry if that's a terrible explanation, but here's the code I'm using:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://web.wm.edu/studenthappenings/preview.php?");

  try {
    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", username));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));

    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();

        // writing response to log
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){ 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What output does this produce? What exactly does "the original source code of the URL" mean?

Comment: So, I have this url, let's call it apps.com. I can print out the original source code of the URL, and it has some CSS, HTML stuff. When I login to apps.com with bogus credentials (username: Jup, Password: NotEvenRegistered), I can view the source code that displays some kind of error: "Cannot login, recheck credentials." However, when I try to reproduce the same thing in Java (Eclipse IDE) by reading that source code with the error message, it just displays the starting source code of apps.com. Sorry if that was confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(responseString);
```

The response is held in the body of the `HttpResponse`. You can use `EntityUtils` to get the `string` body from the `HttpEntity` in the `HttpResponse`.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but as far as I can tell, this does not work. When I print the responseString aka the source code of that URL, I still can't find the error message that's supposed to be there, akin to "Couldn't connect..." It still just displays the original source code of the URL.


Perhaps the solution I want is not possible? I can see the source code error message on my browser, but not when I print it. Note: this is mainly for testing purposes, I just want to see if my code does what it says it does.

Comment: Are you posting to their php login FUNCTION, or to their login WEB PAGE. There needs to be a back end to handle the http request, and then form an http response and send it back to you.

Comment: I'm posting to their login web page, I don't even know how I would post to their php login function. And right, I understand that there has to be communication for http, but would I need that here? All I'm viewing is the resulting source code from the URL. 


You can probably tell I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Think of it like ordering at a restaurant. When you go in, you ask the waiter for your food, and after they are finished making it, he will bring it out to you. If there is no waiter to ask for the food, you will probably not end up getting any food. Http requests work similar to this, there needs to be something on the server side (your school's side) to take that request, process it, and give something back to you. My guess, is that they probably don't have this exposed or open to where you can do so. I would need to see their source (which you should probably not be posting), or an API.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. Although they must have something exposed, as I just noticed something new when I read the responseString; there is some new message, "note that your data...", displayed, different from what was the original source code of the URL. So, that's progress.

Comment: If they do, then it comes down to sending a request in the right format. Some functions handle query params (`/login.php?user='mike'&pass='Elofson'`), some want the request in the body. Generally, post requests are made in the body of the post. So you just need to know the format that it is expecting it in. Without more information, there isn't a whole lot that I can do for you. I would need the full response you get, error messages, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Mike, I really appreciate it. I'll get to the bottom of this eventually.

Comment: Sure thing. Happy to help as much as I can, let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: Could I ask one more question?

I decided to use the jsoup library instead, as it's much cleaner and easier to use. I'm able to post data to the website, but it doesn't let me login. I've reviewed all input fields, got cookies using a GET request, and verified my login credentials are correct, but no luck. Vague question, yes, but just wondering if I'd be able to bug you a bit more.

Comment: Sure, but there wasn't really a question in that comment. What is the response code that you are getting from the server?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I've fixed everything. Instead of Jsoup, I decided to go back to HttpClient. I wasn't able to login to the server because I wasn't posting the full and correct post data, as well as the fact that I wasn't getting all the right cookies; I had to use Chrome's "Inspect Element" feature for that. Thanks for all your help though, @Mike Elofson.